# why this result use column of parent table in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
create table teacher (
        id int,
        name varchar(126),
        primary key(id)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table class (
        id int,
        name varchar(126),
        t_id int,
        primary key(id),
        foreign key (t_id) references  teacher(id)  on delete cascade on update cascade
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

data in tables

```
mysql> select * from teacher ;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | yang |
|  2 | yan  |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from  class ;
+----+---------+------+
| id | name    | t_id |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | math    |    1 |
|  2 | english |    2 |
+----+---------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

sql I execute

```
mysql> select * from  class   where  t_id = (select t_id from teacher where name = 'yang');
+----+---------+------+
| id | name    | t_id |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | math    |    1 |
|  2 | english |    2 |
+----+---------+------+
```

how this sql executed and t_id parsed in subsql;

ps:this sql is not what I want, a bug one, but want to know how this run in mysql.

Comment: You are getting the t_id incorrect inside subquery... mysql> select * from  class   where  t_id = (select id from teacher where name = 'yang')

Comment: What is it you want to know? How subqueries work in general, or specifically how the query plan for this one is built up? Both questions seem quite simple and therefore have probably been answered before.

Comment: @underscore_d  how this sql come to this result specifically, not care about if this sql  is correct or not .